# Mathematica z-value mesh in plots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mesh

I have a list of `{x,y,z}` values and I am using a ListDensityPlot to visualize it. I want to draw contours with something like `MeshFunctions->{#3&}`. This is what I have now:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange->{0, 350}, Mesh->{10}, MeshFunctions->{#3 &}]
```

But I want the values of contours to grow exponentially from the minimum value of `z` up to the maximum range (which is 350). How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a single number (like 10) to `Mesh`, you're asking for that many contours, evenly spaced. But if you give it a list of values, contours will be drawn at those points.

So all we need now is a list of ten numbers (let's say `n` numbers) increasing exponentially from the minimum value (call it `min`) to the maximum (call it `max`). We can generate it like this -- the proof is left as an exercise:

```
Table[
    min Exp[i Log[max / min] / (n - 1)],
    {i, 0, n - 1}
]
```

So the solution to your problem is:

```
min = Min[data[[All, 3]]];
ListDensityPlot[
    data,
    PlotRange->{0, 350},
    Mesh->{Table[
        min Exp[i Log[350 / min] / 9],
        {i, 0, 9}
    ]},
    MeshFunctions->{#3 &}
]
```

Note the extra braces around the `Table` call, which make that list of values the specification for a single mesh.

Comment: Any chance you'd be interested in joining us over at [mathematica.se]?

Comment: Probably not. I think it makes more sense for a programming language to have a Stack Exchange tag than its own site.

Comment: To each their own. But, I'd like to point out that a good portion of Mathematica is not inherently programming, as discussed [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/3750/37670), and like [tag:latex], Mathematica questions have regularly been closed for being off-topic.

Comment: (Obviously by "Stack Exchange tag" I meant "Stack Overflow tag" -- my kingdom for an edit button.) I don't have a strong enough opinion to get deeply involved in the discussion, but I'm unlikely to move over to a new site. Enjoy, though!

Comment: Although, if you answer enough of these, one of them is likely to be migrated at one point ... :)